# How to interpret the TI (texas instruments) SensorTag movement-sensor data components?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, accelerometer, core-bluetooth

I am printing to the console the various components read by the movement service (magnitude, acceleration, and gyro).

I am a little confused as my assumptions/intuition seems incorrect.

For instance, when the device is angled/tilted in a certain way i see continuous reading where the magnitude is greater than 100. This is even though the device itself is hardly moving (if any). I would expect the magnitude to be close to zero (0) since the device is not moving at all.

I am doing simple vector math to get the magnitude based on the 3D coordinate that the device outputs from the **didGetNotificaiton** delegated method. By simple math i mean getting the vector length from the Magnitude 3d coordinate.

Here is a sample data point.

```
Movement magnetic= 134.824387985183.
Movement acceleration = 8.46825231870429.
Movement gyro = 16.482123031426.
```

**Can anybody point me to any doc/ref/example that explains these movement components?**

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question correctly we need to know what is the exact model of the *SensorTag* that you have. But I can help with a basic explanation on what the numbers represent.

Each sensor tag contains multiple MEMS (Micro Electro-Mechanical Systems) in which only the datasheet of that sensor MEMS will describe how to decode that information. Important details of each sensor MEMS specification document will be the "measurement range" and the "measurement sensitivity", in which the following example should help. Please note that the following example was created based on the specification of the Multi-standard SensorTag that uses the CC2650 wireless MCU. This sensor tag uses an Invensense MCU as a gyroscope, accelerometer and compass (see https://www.invensense.com/products/motion-tracking/9-axis/mpu-9250/)

Focusing only on the accelerometer for this example, the documentation shows the accelerometer "Full-Scale Range" (red box) and the "Sensitivity Scale Factor" (blue box).

[Accelerometer Specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaKBN.png)

Since this MCU provides accelerometer data in 16 bits, this means that we have 2^16 = 65,535 data points that can be used to convert data. If the sensor MEMS is programmed to use the ±2g range, this means that we have the sensitivity of 16,384 LSB/g. In other specifications documents, it is common to express this value in mg/LSB which, in this case, will be 0.061 mg/LSB. This means that each time the LSB of the output changes by 1, it will represent a change of 0.061 mg.

As an example, an accelerometer resting in a table, experiences the gravitational acceleration (1 g) pointing to the floor (negative Z axis), therefore, to maintain equilibrium and since it is flat on the table the accelerometer will read 1 g pointing to the sky (Z axis).

So, the value of the z-axis component of the accelerometer when it is flat on a table, should be 16500. Because,

16500 LSB * 0.061 mg/LSB = 1,006.5 mg ≈ 1 g

Once this is applied to all axis of the accelerometer (or a Gyro with its own values) you will have a vector in desired units.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is the [wiki](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Main_Page) pages for every sensortag. Find yours and there will be detail explanations.

All right. What is the device model that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct link for the newest SensorTag model http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag2015

For the old SensorTag model go to http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2541_SensorTag